# ¿Cómo iterar correctamente una variable calculada en vue3 + vuex4 + ionic5?

Tags: vue.js, ionic

Tengo un pequeño inconveniente a la hora de iterar una variable computada en vue 3. Por lo que leí, vue trabajo ahora con Proxys para sus valores reactivos.
El problema que tengo ahora, es que al iterar dicha variable, me itera los valores que me retorna el Proxy, es decir.
Esta es la manera en que uso la computada

```
setup() {
const store = useStore()
const cat: ComputedRef<Categories[]> = computed(() => store.state.categories)
console.log(cat)
const slideOpts = {
  loop: true,
  // spaceBetween: 0,
  slidesPerView: 4.5,
  initialSlide: 0,
  speed: 400
};
const colors = randomColors()
return { slideOpts, colors, cat} }
```

Este es la manera en que itero los valores

```
    <ion-slides :options="slideOpts">
    <ion-slide v-for="category in categories" class="category__content-card">
        <ion-card :class="colors">
            <ion-card-content>
                <ion-avatar>
                    <img src="https://gravatar.com/avatar/dba6bae8c566f9d4041fb9cd9ada7741?d=identicon&f=y">
                </ion-avatar>
            </ion-card-content>
        </ion-card>
        <ion-label class="category__name">{{ category }} </ion-label>
    </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

Esta es una imagen del console de la constante cat

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Acá debes indicar qué quieres mostrar de categoria:

```
<ion-label class="category__name">{{ category }} </ion-label>
```

Allí estas mostrando todo el objeto de categoría, deberías indicar una propiedad:

```
<ion-label class="category__name">{{ category.name }} </ion-label>
```

Comment: Como puedes ver en la imagen, se están renderizando 3 slides, en los cuales, sólo uno tiene el array que supongo yo, es la propiedad [[Target]] del proxy, si pongo <ion-label class="category__name">{{ category.name }} </ion-label>, no aparecerá nada porque el proxy está retornando completamente y no los valores

Comment: Ya cierto, es que muestra 3 porque categories tienes 3 propiedades al iterar por el objeto es la segunda propiedad la que tiene el array de alli que se muestre asi

Comment: Sí, pero yo no le agrego las propiedades, se agregan solas y no sé cómo acceder a esas propiedades.

Comment: Si colocas en el v-for:  <ion-slide v-for="category in categories.target.categories" ??, dejando el category.name luego

Comment: Tampoco funciona así, cuando pongo eso, no muestra el componente.